# Django pagination query duplicated, double the time

Tags: django, pagination, query-optimization, django-queryset

In my current project I want to do some filtering and ordering on a queryset and show it to the user in a paginated form.
This works fine, however I am not comfortable with the performance.
When I use and order_by statement either explicitly or implicitly with the model Meta ordering, I can see in the Debug toolbar that this query is essentially executed twice.
Once for the paginator count (without the ORDER BY) and once to fetch the objects slice (with ORDER BY).
From my observation this leads to doubling the time it takes.

Is there any way this can be optimized?

Below is a minimal working example, in my actual app I use class based views.

```
class Medium(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('title'),
                             max_length=256,
                             null=False, blank=False,
                             db_index=True,
                             )
    offered_by = models.ForeignKey(Institution,
                                   verbose_name=_('Offered by'),
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Quantity'),
                                   validators=[
                                       MinValueValidator(0)
                                   ],
                                   null=False, blank=False,
                                   )
    deleted = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Deleted'),
                                  default=False,
                                  )
```

```
def index3(request):
    media = Medium.objects.filter(deleted=False, quantity__gte=0)
    media = media.exclude(offered_by_id=request.user.institution_id)
    media = media.filter(title__icontains="funktion")
    media = media.order_by('title')
    paginator = Paginator(media, 25)
    media = paginator.page(1)
    return render(request, 'media/empty2.html', {'media': media})
```

[Debug toolbar sql timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKvHP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not exactly duplicated: One is a `COUNT` query, the other one fetches the actual objects for the specific page requested. This is unavoidable, since Django's `Paginator` needs to know the total number of objects. However, if the queryset `media` isn't too large, you can optimise by forcing the `media` Queryset to be evaluated (just add a line `len(media)` before you define the Paginator).

But note that if `media` is very large, you might not want to force `media` to be evaluated as you're loading all the objects into memory.

Comment: Forcing the queryset to be evaluated unfortunately isn't an option. I was just curious whether there are any other optimizations I could make, since I noticed that the `COUNT` query is missing the `ORDER_BY`. If I omit the `.order_by()` the second query executes much faster. But as I think about it now that makes total sense.

Comment: Then there is no other way than to accept two queries. Of you need the total number of results/pages it’s unavoidable.